# Make the same templates available in meteor-client, meteor-server, as well as regular clients

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the same templates available in three different contexts:

- regular meteor client pages,
- meteor server (as done by [`handlebars-server`](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server) but without requiring separate files), and
- regular javascript clients (for pages served by `iron-router` or similar).

My first hope was to be able to change the [`handlebars-server`](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-handlebars-server) package to not compile `.handlebar` files, but just go through all `.html` files, find the meteor templates defined in them, and then compile their `innerHTML` with the regular `handlebars` package from `npm` and make them available everywhere using their `name` attribute. But I can't seem to get this to work. It seems that Meteor doesn't allow the registration of more than one source handler per file extension.

I would really like to avoid having to write some kind of wrapper start-script that compiles templates before starting meteor and puts them in all the required places. It seems clunky and would interfere with bundle deployment.

Any other ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Take a look at Fast Render (http://meteorhacks.com/fast-render/) and the Meteor Spiderable package. Also keep in mind that Meteor's templating system will change dramatically in a few weeks when 1.0 comes out.